# npm install from git repo does not take the latest

Tags: git, npm

In my `package.json` there is an entry for a dependency which points to our local git repo:

```
"foo" : "git+http://<local_gitlab_repo>/foo.git"
```

So after a `npm install` for the project I go and inspect and manually verify which git commit actually installed.

```
> cat .\node_modules\foo\package.json | select-string "_resolved"
  "_resolved": "git+http://<local_gitlab_repo>/foo.git#ee07ff73bb036be5be6f248ebbac8188da3870ea",
```

Now suppose I have changed something in the git repo, and came back to my node project and did `npm install` and ran the above command, the commit hash doesn't change.

In other words, the latest git commit is not downloaded. However, in order to force this, I manually delete the package folder from `node_modules` and then `npm install`, and then verify with the git repo.

Is there a more direct way to do this via npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install` does not update an already downloaded package. To do that, you can run `npm update`